# Chainlink vs DEXs & NFT Market prices

Tags: nft, chainlink, oracles, decentralized-exchange, price

I am doing a futures dApp, so I need the price of the underlying assets (all assets are on-chain not fiat). What is the difference between using DEX and NFT Marketplace on-chain prices as oracle and using Chainlink?

Is it possible to get prices of not well known NFTs with Chainlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Relying on DEX and NFT Marketplace as a data source is susceptible to a flashloan attack.

More details in: https://medium.com/bandprotocol/why-defi-needs-real-oracles-beyond-dex-9c80cf192883